# what is the reason for getting data.count("and") is 2?

Tags: python

while executing the below code, i'm getting result as 2. someone could tell me the reason for getting 2 in python3x?

```
data="Hands to clap and eyes to see"
data.count("and")
```

2

Comment: Count is also taking `and` from `Hands`

Comment: You need to find your count in the list of words for the correct answer @AbhinayJami Check my answer beo

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

> str.count(sub[, start[, end]])
>   Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end].

As you can see, the string `Hands to clap and eyes to see`  has two `and` strings, one in `Hands` and one in `and`, hence the count is 2

To fix this, you can split the string to list, and then apply count, which will match only full words like `and` and not partial words like `hands`

```
In [115]: data="Hands to clap and eyes to see"                                                                                                                                    
#Split on whitespace to convert string to list of words
In [116]: li = data.split()                                                                                                                                                       
#Find the complete word and in the list
In [117]: li.count('and')                                                                                                                                                         
Out[117]: 1
```